# Porque en php se puede acceder directamente a las variables enviadas en un objeto desde ajax

Tags: php, ajax

¿Alguien sabe porque en php se puede acceder directamente a las variables enviadas por ajax dentro de un objeto sin necesidad de utilizar la funcion json_decode() de php?.
Esta es la funcion que envia el valor "valor":

```
function mi_funcion() {
    var valor = "mi_valor";
    $.ajax({
        url: "mi_archivo.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        //data: "valor="+valor,
        data: {"valor": valor},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            $("#mi_div").text(respuesta["valor"]);
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#mi_div").text("Error");
        },
        timeout: 60000
    });
}
```

Y esta es la parte de php:

```
<?php
$resultado = array();
$resultado["valor"] = $_REQUEST["valor"];
echo json_encode($resultado);
?>
```

P.D.: Lo anterior funciona bien, asi es que mi duda es del porque se accede de la misma manera en php para los siguientes dos casos: 1. data: {"mtdo": mtdo}, y 2. data: "mtdo="+mtdo,
Si en un caso es un objeto y en el otro es una cadena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomado de la documentación de [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> data
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Para resumir un poco lo que dice (y lo que nos importa en este caso), jQuery va a convertir la información de `data` a un string, en caso que no lo sea aún.

En el código de jQuery también podemos ver cuando lo convierte:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L559

```
    // Convert data if not already a string
    if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
        s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
    }
```

Puedes ver lo que hace [jQuery.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) .

---

Por el lado de php, vemos que simplemente vamos a recibir un POST regular, con los datos serializados, y el uso de la variable 'superglobal' `$_REQUEST` va a contener los datos del POST, tal y como lo explica la documentación de php:

[Documentación php: $_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php)

> $_REQUEST — Variables HTTP Request
> Un array asociativo que por defecto contiene el contenido de $_GET, $_POST y $_COOKIE.
>
> Esta es una 'superglobal' o una variable automatic global. Significa simplemente que es una variable que está disponible en cualquier parte del script. No hace falta hacer global $variable; para acceder a la misma desde funciones o métodos.

Comment: Ok entiendo, gracias Shaz.

Answer (score 1):

Si como comentas viene en un objeto de php que se guarda en este caso en las variables `$_REQUEST` y `$_POST` ya que la petición la estas realizando por el método post, ahora bien puede que estés confundiendo el objeto que armas en javascript en el ajax con lo que recibe el php en el servidor.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por contestar andrewvergel, hace un momento edite la ultima parte, creo que no me expleque, lo que pasa es que no se porque se accede de la misma manera en php para los siguientes dos casos: 1. data: {"mtdo": mtdo}, y 2. data: "mtdo="+mtdo.

Comment: @AntonioPerez si en efecto funciona con ambas como coloco **Shaz** en la respuesta anterior. Con esta información

data
Type: PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).